# Is it possible to refresh tab in lightning service console

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, service-console

I have embeded lightning component on Case detail view page and I would like to tirgger refresh of case record page (opened in lightning service console). I tried using `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire()`, but it doesn't work. I also tried with workspaceAPI, but that also doesn't seem to do the trick (it won't open new tab with same record id and it doesn't have function to just do the refresh).

I would prefer to use `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire()` so I would appreciate any ideas why it doesn't work.

I think posting code seems not necessary in this case as I am just trying to trigger the refresh event (`$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire()`) from just button click so nothing advanced involved and I am sure that code executes I just do not see the effect of this function like it would be blocked in some way.

Comment: That's interesting that workspaceAPI doesn't have a refresh method for Lightning console.  I was just about to start using it myself to control some navigation in a console.  If that, and force:refreshView, doesn't do it, I suppose the way I'd solve it is brute force - I'd probably close the tab and reopen it.  If it happens to be a parent tab, I'd save off the locations of the subtabs and recreate them all after closing/opening the parent tab.  Not an elegant solution (which is why I'm not posting as an answer), but if it's only way, it's probably how I'd handle it.

Comment: As you mentioned, there currently isnt a method in the workspaceAPI to handle refreshing a tab. You can try this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199526/lightning-service-console-refresh-tab

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost a year ago so the answer may be anachronistic, but there is now a refresh tab method. Documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_refreshTab.htm